# Compute the expected number of elements in a data stream equipped with deletion

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Given a finite universe $\mathcal{U} =  \{u_1, u_2, ..., u_m\}$, a sequence of elements drawn from $\mathcal{U}$. Denote $u_i$ is drawn with probability $p_i$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^m p_i = 1$. Suppose that when sampling, we also conduct a deletion operation so as to delete the duplicate. Denote the probability of successful deletion of element $u_i$ is $Pr_i$. For example, the universe is $\mathcal{U} = \{1,2, ...,9\}$ and a sequence of elements sampled by now is $3, 5, 1, 2$. Suppose the next element drawn from the universe is $5$. Before appending $5$ to the sequence, we first try to remove the existing $5$. If succeed, the sequence becomes $3, 1, 2, 5$. If fail, the sequence becomes $3, 5, 1, 2, 5$. Assume that it failed and the next sampled elements are $6, 7$, then the sequence becomes $3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7$. There is no deletion because $6, 7$ do not ever appear before. Assume that then $2$ is sampled. Similarly, we delete the old $2$ with a certain success probability. If succeed, the sequence becomes $3, 5, 1, 5, 6, 7, 2$; otherwise, $3, 5, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 2$. I want to know the expected number of elements (the expected length of the sequence) after $n$ times sampling.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Assume the sequence is "3,5,1,2,5" and yet another 5 is sampled, will the process try to delete both existing 5 ?

Comment: Good question. Sorry for the misunderstanding. The process only tries to delete the last 5.

Comment: How is the related to complex analysis?

Comment: Space complexity?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a universe with just one member, i.e. $\mathcal{U} =  \{u_1\}$

The samples will be

$\mathcal{s[1]} =  u_1$

$\mathcal{s[2]} =  u_1$

$\mathcal{s[3]} =  u_1$

and so on.

When sample 2 is made, sample 1 will be deleted with the probability $(1 - Pr_1)$

When sample 3 is made, sample 2 will be deleted with the probability $(1 - Pr_1)$

And so on.

In other words, all samples except the last will be deleted with the probability $(1 - Pr_1)$.

So after be $n$ samples we have an average of $(n - 1)(1 - Pr_1) + 1$. For a high value of $n$ that is approximately $n(1 - Pr_1)$.

Now consider a universe with two members, i.e. $\mathcal{U} =  \{u_1, u_2\}$

After $n$ samples the average number of samples that was $u_1$ will be $n p_1$ and the average number of samples that was $u_2$ will be $n p_2$.

Combine that with the result of the deletion process described initially and we get the final average length to be $n p_1 (1 - Pr_1) + n p_2 (1 - Pr_2)$.

In the general case we can write:

average length = $n \sum_{i = 1}^m p_i (1 - Pr_i)$